# Visual Studio 2017 does not have PropertyGrid

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2017

I want to use PropertGrid control but I can't find it in the toolbox. I am working on a winforms project. Can someone help me?

[image]

Comment: You should open a design surface like a `Form` in design view. Then the toolbox will be populated with suitable controls for the framework. It's located in `All Windows Forms` group.

Comment: I did. I reuploaded the screenshot.

Comment: I don't think there is any difference with how it [was](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/using-property-grid-in-C-Sharp/) in earlier VS versions.

Answer (score 1):

right click in toolbox panel.
select choose items...
in first tab(.NET framework components) check property grid.